# MySQL Query for Returning New Visitors from Database

Tags: mysql, optimization

Suppose I have a table that logs incoming users where each user has an IP address (ipaddr).

What's the best way to select all users that have never come to the site before? (so that particular IPADDR value only exists in the table **once** ), however I only want to know about the new visitors that came in the last 6 hours.

I basically want to do something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT * from visitors GROUP BY ipaddr WHERE COUNT(ipaddr) = 1 and date > '2011-03-31 00:59:11'
```

HOWEVER, the DATE condition should only apply to the results, and not for checking if the visitors is new or not.

UPDATE:

There is an SID field that accounts for user browsing sessions.

Here's the relevant table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `visitors` (
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sid` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ipaddr` int(8) NOT NULL,
)
```

Some example data:

```
INSERT INTO `visitors` (`date`,`sid`, `ipaddr`)
VALUES
    ('2011-03-31 06:25:48', 299521885457, -1454342140);


INSERT INTO `visitors` (`date`,`sid`, `ipaddr`)
VALUES
    ('2011-03-31 06:26:37', 299521885457, -1454342140);


INSERT INTO `visitors` (`date`,`sid`, `ipaddr`)
VALUES
    ('2010-01-01 15:23:44', 694387538590, -1454342140);
```

This visitor has two rows for his current session happening in realtime, each row is for each page he has visited (only relevant schema shown). The last example row shown is a visit from 2010, which means this ip address has 2 different SIDs belonging to it, therefore is not a new visitors.

The query's result should have  none of the rows listed above, seeing as how this visitor has two sessions in the database. If the last row is removed (with sid 694387538590), the visitor should become a new visitor and appear in the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `"WHERE"` for `GROUP BY` is `HAVING`:

```
SELECT ipaddr from visitors
GROUP BY ipaddr
HAVING COUNT(ipaddr) = 1 AND MIN(date) > '2011-03-31 00:59:11'
```

### UPDATE

```
SELECT ipaddr, max(sid) sid
  FROM visitors
 GROUP BY ipaddr
HAVING     COUNT(DISTINCT sid) = 1
       AND MIN(date) > '2011-03-31 00:59:11'
```

**Explanation:**

```
SELECT date, sid, ipaddr FROM visitors

date                sid        ipaddr 
------------------------------------------
2011-03-31 06:25:48 299525457  -1454342140 
2011-03-31 06:26:37 299525457  -1454342140 
2010-01-01 15:23:44 694388590  -1454342140 
2011-03-31 11:23:44 111111111  -1234444811 
2011-03-31 12:23:44 111111111  -1234444811

SELECT ipaddr FROM visitors GROUP BY ipaddr

ipaddr
-----------
-1454342140 
-1234444811 

--- group for ip -1454342140 ---

2011-03-31 06:25:48 299525457  -1454342140 
2011-03-31 06:26:37 299525457  -1454342140 
2010-01-01 15:23:44 694388590  -1454342140

COUNT(DISTINCT sid) = COUNT(299525457, 694388590) = 2
--> there is more than 1 session for this ip: not good!!!

  ==> group discarded

--- group for ip -1234444811 ---

2011-03-31 11:23:44 111111111  -1234444811 
2011-03-31 12:23:44 111111111  -1234444811

COUNT(DISTINCT sid) = COUNT(111111111) = 1 --> OK
(here COUNT(sid) = count(111111111, 111111111) = 2
 --> despite it is the same sid, the count is 2, that is why using DISTINCT)

MIN(date) = '2011-03-31 11:23:44' > '2011-03-31 00:59:11' --> OK

  ==> group accepted
```

Authorized columns in the `SELECT` are:

- columns used in the `GROUP BY` clause
- agregates of the other columns

`ipaddr` was used in GROUP BY but not `sid`. To have also `sid` I used MAX but remember that it will be applied only to the group of rows for current `ipaddr` and because of the conditions in the query there is 1 unique `sid` but repeated so the result will be that `sid`

Comment: Hmm this seems to do what I described. Can you please explain how this query works? I thought that GROUP BY is applied before HAVING, therefore GROUP by would leave 1 row per ipaddr. Then, wouldn't count(ipaddr) equal 1 for all the rows left after GROUP BY?

Comment: the HAVING clause is used to filter on Aggregates (SUM, COUNT, AVG), the WHERE clause filters on conditions. So it does GROUP BY first and then eliminates all the records that don't meet the HAVING condition.

Comment: the `HAVING` clause is used with aggregate functions to filter groups produced by `GROUP BY`, i.e.: before returning `ipaddr`, `count(ipaddr) = 1` is evaluated against the group of rows with that `ipaddr`

Comment: Would it make sense to have an index on IPADDR, or can HAVING not make use of that index?

Comment: The index, if it can help, is with the `GROUP BY` (not HAVING as the rows are already there). More explanation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: Updated my question, any ideas on how to modify the query to include the extra condition?

Comment: compare `Min(date)` to your date parameter

Comment: Ah, that works perfectly. Suppose I give each user's session a session id (sid). That way, there can be multiple rows of a single ipaddr, but as long as they all share the same sid, it counts as one visit. Any ideas how to find which visitors only visited once via SID instead? Thanks a ton I really appreciate the help.

Comment: same but `GROUP BY sid` (`max(ipaddr)` works because you have a unique `ipaddr` for each `sid`):

`SELECT sid, max(ipaddr) from visitors
  GROUP BY sid
 HAVING COUNT(ipaddr) = 1 AND MIN(date) > '2011-03-31 00:59:11`

Comment: Won't max(ipaddr) return the largest IP address value? The query isn't working correctly, its reporting a new visitor that isn't in fact new (has a session under same IP addrress from a year ago). I don't understand the point of max(ipaddr)

Comment: Regarding your previous comment, assume that each session by the same user has the same ipaddr values

Comment: can you add to the question a example of your data (table: sid, user, ipaddr, date) and what you expect the result to be?

Comment: Thank you so much! That does exactly what I wanted. Is there any chance you could explain the query? Particularly the reason for using max(sid) and COUNT(DISTINCT sid)?

Comment: Doesn't max(sid) return the largest value of sid? The sid column isn't organized to sequentially, they are random numbers.